# website with 4 horizontal fluid pages

Tags: jquery, html, css

I am wanting to make a website with 4 pages (a,b,c and d) that are `fluid`(?) so that they change width depending on the width of the device.

I want the minimum width to be the width of the device. But if the contents is any greater for it to not worry. Then I want there to be a hyperlink to the beginning of each page.

This is what I have tried

## HTML:

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <th id="a" scope="col">a</th>
        <th id="b" scope="col">b</th>
        <th id="c" scope="col">c</th>
        <th id="d" scope="col">d</th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>&nbsp;</td>
        <td>&nbsp;</td>
        <td>&nbsp;</td>
        <td>&nbsp;</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>&nbsp;</td>
        <td>&nbsp;</td>
        <td>&nbsp;</td>
        <td>&nbsp;</td>
    </tr>
</table>
<table>
    <tr>
        <th scope="col"><a href="#a"> a </a>
        </th>
        <th scope="col"><a href="#b"> b </a>
        </th>
        <th scope="col"><a href="#c"> c </a>
        </th>
        <th scope="col"><a href="#d"> d</a>
        </th>
    </tr>
</table>
```

## JQUERY:

```
$(document).ready(function() {

$("#a").css({'width':''+$(window).width()});

$("#b").css({'width':''+$(window).width()});

$("#c").css({'width':''+$(window).width()});

$("#d").css({'width':''+$(window).width()});

});
```

## [JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/ndTH7/)

But as you can see in the `fiddle` it is not doing anything as I said

Comment: If you inspect your elements, they are getting the width, however because you have the layout in a table you are running into problems. I would never use tables to control your layout, so you might want to re-think this.

Comment: How should i controll my layout?

Comment: HTML5 tags or `<div>` tags. If you want a nice fluid website template, check out Bootstrap. Documentation here [http://getbootstrap.com/getting-started/#template](http://getbootstrap.com/getting-started/#template)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To have horizontaly aligned panels that are responsive, you can easily use CSS only. 
Here is a demo: http://jsfiddle.net/NicoO/ndTH7/2/

The width of each panel will always be at least the current browser width. If the content is longer than that, the panel will expand.

The CSS Looks like this:

```
*
{
    -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
    -webkit-box-sizing: border-box; 
    box-sizing: border-box;
}

html, body
{
   height:100%;  
}
body
{
    margin:0;
    padding:0;  
}

.links
{
    position: fixed;
    top:0;
    padding: 8px 0px;
    list-style: none;
    width: 100%;
}
.links li
{
    display: inline-block;
}

.panels
{
    white-space: nowrap;
    height: inherit;
}

.panel
{
   height: inherit;
   font-size: 20px;
   text-align: center;
   padding: 20px;
   display: inline-block;
   min-width: 100%;
}

.stupid-long-content
{
    width: 3000px;
    display: block;
}

/* look up inline-block space */
.panel + .panel
{
    margin-left: -4px;
}

#a
{
    background-color: green;   
}

#b
{
    background-color: red;   
}

#c
{
    background-color: blue;   
}

#d
{
    background-color: silver;   
}
```

With this HTML:

```
<ul class="links">
    <li><a href="#a">A</a></li>
    <li><a href="#b">B</a></li>
    <li><a href="#c">C</a></li>
    <li><a href="#d">D</a></li>
</ul>
<div class="panels">
    <div class="panel" id="a">Hi</div>
    <div class="panel" id="b">Hello</div>
    <div class="panel" id="c"><span class="stupid-long-content">Morning</span></div>
    <div class="panel" id="d">Test</div>
</div>
```

Pretty easy, fully responsive and it does not need any JS.

Comment: I am looking for 4 **horizontal** pages? With the possibilty of the pages to be larger than the width of the screen

Comment: This seems to hyperlink very strangely. Is there anyway to link it to the beginning (left) of the colour?

Comment: I dont think i understand you question. What do you mean exactly by linking very strangely? when you click on A, you will see the first panel with `id="a"`

Comment: so say if b and c overlap. and you click c it does not go to c. Also if you are on d and you click c it goes to the end of c not the beginning?

Comment: There is no overlapping at all. The panels are next to each other with no room between them. When you click on the navigation, your viewport will jump to the left edge of the said panel. Maybe you have trouble seeing that Panel C is very long: 3000px, to demonstrate the expanding of the panel, when it's content is very long. here is a more visual demo: http://jsfiddle.net/NicoO/ndTH7/3/

Comment: let me explain with the new example. When you can see "I'am D" and you click the link "C" why does it not show "I'am C" it shows the end of the div?

Comment: When i see "I'am D" and click in "C" i do see "I'am C". Which browser are you using?

Comment: chrome it goes to the end of the div

Comment: Now i understand what your problem is. When you scrolled between b and c and press b, you won't scroll back, because the browser knows you are already there. Well this is a new question for SO. You asked for layout you have it. p.s don't edit answer to clearify questions, that will be an invalid edit.